# Python: Saving list in a file without quotes?

Tags: python, list, python-2.x, csv

I'm working with a couple text files using csv module and I encountered something strange that I can't understand. My code so far:

```
import csv

with open('file1.txt', 'r') as a:
    with open('file2.txt', 'w+') as b:
        reader = csv.reader(a, delimiter = '\t')
        writer = csv.writer(b, delimiter = '\t', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar = '')

        for row in reader:
            # Do stuff

            writer.writerow(row)

            # Check datatypes of each column
            print(type(row))
            print(type(row[0]))
            print(type(row[1]))
            print(type(row[2]))
            print(type(row[3]))
            print(type(row[4]))
            print(row)
```

Output:

```
<type 'list'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'list'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'list'>
['blah', 'blah', ['01', '02', '03', '04'], 'blah', ['0', '0', '0', '0']]
```

I was happy until I opened file2.txt again to do further processing but I could not because I was getting confusing results so I again checked the types and this time the output was different.

```
with open('file2.txt', 'r+') as c:

    reader = csv.reader(c, delimiter = '\t')

    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        print(type(row))
        print(type(row[0]))
        print(type(row[1]))
        print(type(row[2]))
        print(type(row[3]))
        print(type(row[4]))
```

Output:

```
['blah', 'blah', "['01', '02', '03', '04']", 'blah', "['0', '0', '0', '0']"]
<type 'list'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
```

Notice the double quotes around 3rd and 5th values. How did those values got converted to string!? This is strange to me. I really need to have 3rd and 5th column to be of list type instead of string to be able to work on it further.

My question is that how do I convert those 3rd and 5th column values back to list type OR even better how do I prevent them to be saved as strings in the first place?

Please let me know if I need to clarify my question further and please do help me to deal with this situation.

**Edit:** So, I have learned that it is not possible to prevent those values to be stored as string, so I'm now thinking if I can get to work on those values as list. I really don't care how values are stored in file as long as I get to work on them as lists.

Comment: for each of the items, check it for square brackets then convert it with list(row[index])

Comment: When you serialise a `list`, the CSV writer convert it to string, so that you get quotes: `str(['01', '02', '03', '04']) => "['01', '02', '03', '04']"`

Comment: You might want to try `pickle` or `cPickle` to save and load list objects directly.

Comment: @RodrigoDorantes-Gilardi Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent them from being saved as strings. Obviously, a CSV is a text file; it doesn't know anything about lists. Anything passed to `csv.writerow` is going to be converted to a string, by calling `str()` on it. If that resulting string contains commas, it will itself be quoted so that it is obvious that the commas are part of the element, rather than being a separator denoting a new element.

There's no way to automatically convert back to a list. If you know that column 2 of every row should be a list, you could manually convert it back - one way of doing this would be to use `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: Oh, what a bummer actually. I tried `list(literal_eval(row[2]))` and `print(row[2][0])` prints `[` which means `row[2]` is still being treated as a string. Can you update your answer with the correct usage of `literal_eval`?

Answer (score 1):

Using `pickle` you can save your object (list, in this case) as a serialized byte stream that you can then load back and reconvert that byte stream to a python object.

Here is an example of how it works.

```
import pickle
writer = ['foo', 'bar', ['foo', 'bar'], 2]
pickle.dump(writer, open('file2.p', 'wb'))
```

When you'll load `file2.p` with pickle it will be reconverted to its original object:

```
writer = pickle.load(open('file2.p', 'rb'))
print(writer)
```

Gives,

```
['foo', 'bar', ['foo', 'bar'], 2]
```

**Edit:**

To create `writer`:

```
import csv
writer = []
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as a:
    reader = csv.reader(a, delimiter = '\t')
    for row in reader:
        writer.append(row)
```

Comment: This worked for me. Saving as a pickle file also makes it much smaller in size than a csv file. This works if there are multiple lists as columns in the dataframe too.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Pandas `DataFrame` class instead? It has much better coverage of different CSV specs and much better control over the datatypes of individual columns. Check this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). You can read CSV and then write to another CSV with another delimiter very easily.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to flatten you row in order to convert list of lists in a single list.

Here is an example:

```
def flatten(seq):
    result = []
    for item in seq:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            result.extend(item)
        else:
            result.append(item)
    return result
```

Simple usage:

```
row = ['blah', 'blah', ['01', '02', '03', '04'], 'blah', ['0', '0', '0', '0']]
row = flatten(row)
# -> ['blah', 'blah', '01', '02', '03', '04', 'blah', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

I would correct you code like this:

```
import csv

with open('file1.txt', 'r') as a:
    with open('file2.txt', 'w+') as b:
        reader = csv.reader(a, delimiter = '\t')
        writer = csv.writer(b, delimiter = '\t', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar = '')

        for row in reader:
            # Do stuff

            writer.writerow(flatten(row))
```

Comment: Sorry flattening is beyond my options because in that case I won't be able to access `row[2]` elements like I want to like a list e.g. `row[2][0]` to access `'01'`.

Comment: Do you really need CSV? JSON format is better for encapsulated objects.

Comment: Actually, files that I'm working on are available to me as tab-delimited csv files. So, I really don't have much freedom there.

Comment: Ok, so use Daniel's answer. You have: ˋassert ast.literal_eval(str(['1', '2', '3'])) == ['1', '2', '3']ˋ.